# Alternative to UK's Tier 5 (Youth Mobility Scheme) visa for Indians

Tags: united-kingdom, working-visas

I want to live and work in the UK.

The UK Govt. offers [Tier 5 (Youth Mobility Scheme) visa](https://www.gov.uk/tier-5-youth-mobility) to live and work for 2 years, but  these visa type is not applicable for Indians.

What is the alternative visa to work and live in UK up-to 2 years, if you are an Indian ?

Comment: Most of the other things [listed on the Work Visas page](https://www.gov.uk/browse/visas-immigration/work-visas)?